# DBreeze not running properly in mono

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono, fsync

I'm submitting this question for two reasons: I'm having difficulties using `DBreeze` database engine running under `Mono`, but I've found a workaround, it may help others resolving this exact problem (I post the workaround as an answer), and if anyone else knows a better solution I'd be thankful for the help.

The problem is [DBreeze](https://github.com/hhblaze/DBreeze) is working properly on Windows, but on Linux with Mono right after initalization of the engine and the first insert it throws the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: DBreeze.Exceptions.DBreezeException: Getting table "@utt2"
from the schema failed! ---> DBreeze.Exceptions.TableNotOperableException:
DBreeze.Scheme ---> DBreeze.Exceptions.DBreezeException: Rollback of the table
"DBreeze.Scheme" failed! ---> DBreeze.Exceptions.DBreezeException: Restore
rollback file "./DB/_DBreezeSchema" failed! --->
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: FlushFileBuffers
```

The problem is in the `DBreeze/Storage/FSR.cs` file, because it tries to call

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool FlushFileBuffers(IntPtr hFile);
```

but this is not supported in Mono.

Question is: How to properly flush the filebuffer/call the equivalent as kernel32.dll's `FlushFileBuffers()` to write the buffer contents to the disk under Mono?

Comment: To fit into this site’s format please edit this to be a question and add the answer as an answer below. The question shouldn’t be answered in itself

Comment: Thank You for the advice, I've split it.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is the following:

Since this method would sync the data from the OS file buffer to the hard drive (or any block device) the native unix `fsync` method is able to do the same thing.

The workaround that worked for me was replacing the DllImport above with a custom function:

```
        // [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        // private static extern bool FlushFileBuffers(IntPtr hFile);
        private static bool FlushFileBuffers(IntPtr handle)
        {
            return Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.fsync(handle.ToInt32()) == 0 ? true : false;
        }
```

`fsync` returns `0` if there is no error and `-1` if there is error, the handle must be casted to `int` from `IntPtr`.

During compilation the parameter `/r:Mono.Posix.dll` must be added in the command line to access `fsync` native syscall.

I'm not completely sure this trick would work exactly as it was intended in the original code, because flushing the buffer has different levels depending on the OS, so please tell me if there is any better/proper solution for this problem, or this solution I've found is proper at all.

Answer (score 0):

For .net40 and higher you can use a function.

```
#if NET40
    public static void NET_Flush(FileStream mfs)
    {
        mfs.Flush(true);
    }
#else

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool FlushFileBuffers(IntPtr hFile);

    public static void NET_Flush(FileStream mfs)
    {
        mfs.Flush();
        IntPtr handle = mfs.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

        if (!FlushFileBuffers(handle))
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
    }
#endif
```